# How to get 2 highest values from Laravel array of objects with different indexes

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, logic, back

I need to take an object with 4 different fields and keep only the 2 with the highest values. How can I achieve that? I'm new to Laravel, and with JavaScript, I handled it, but I can't find a better way to do it in Laravel.

**My object**

```
{"res1":158,"res2":97,"res3":99,"res4":103} //it may vary
```

**What I need**

```
{"res1":158,"res4":103} //two with the highest values
```

Comment: Hello! Can you tell me more about the data structure of this particular data? How is it defined on the backend? As an array or a collection from database?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Collection helper.

```
$sorted = $collection
    ->sortByDesc(function($value, $key) {
        return $value;
    })
    ->take(2);
```